# How can i intentionally access the "Index of /" page on my local server?

Tags: html, localserver

So i use a localserver to run a webpage on my local machine - which works fine. But how can i access the parent folder which shows all files saved on that local server? Like the "Index of/" page that gets loaded when you don't have an index.html on your webhost. One time i somehow got to this "Home Panel" of the localserver, but i don't remember how. Thank you!

[Here's an image!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOfb0.jpg)

[Image 2!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSXvJ.jpg)

[Image 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpVzl.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question isn't clear, if you want to show another first directory instead of index.html you can set this with a document ".htaccess" but honestly this isn't often necessary, if you see some sites that show the first page as "home" you can achieve this by "friendly url"  by using .htacess and php, (there is another ways but this is the most common)  this sites have as well the index but this first file just is used to load the others, pls show some example of what you really want, that if that's the case I can provide the code to you.

you can read a little more about the ".htaccess" here https://www.getfilecloud.com/blog/htaccess-for-beginners/

[UPDATE] This is my localhost accessing a subfolder without a index.html
[image]

Comment: hey thanks for your fast answer! i added an image! Thats what i meant, this "index of /" page that's shown when there is no index.html on my server. So to achieve this on the localserver, i could create an file (.htaccess) in which i can declare some 'default behaviour' in case there is no index.html? I'm sorry for my "un-clearness" :-)

Comment: I accessed the http://sumproblems.com/  to have this in your localserver  isn't necessary anything just access your "http://localhost" this will show all your folders in that location and if you access a subfolder like http://localhost/test/  if this was without a index.html will show all folders in the same way, I updated the answer with a image of my localhost access like that

Comment: yes, it's showing that on sumproblems.com - because i have no index.html/index.php files there. but i still can't access it on my localhost. i guess i have to find out where i have to put the .htaccess file. But the localserver is created by the plugin 'Live Server', do you maybe now the path where the plugin stores it's data? It seems to me you are using wamp or something like it?

Comment: If I get this straight there is no need to use .htaccess just access your "localhost/yourfolder" without a index.html that it will provide the same as your online server, what's your local server? I'm using XAMPP

Comment: i got it! i had just to change the settings of the Live Server extension - i added the line "liveServer.settings.root": "/dist", created a "dist" folder in my project's directory, and access it with http://localhost:5500/ i'll add a picture - thank you! I'll try some more things out!

Comment: yes, you are right, there is no need, i was just curious how i could access it/how to intentionally create that behaviour on a localhost.

Comment: and i don't even had to change the settings - it is just a matter of NOT having an index.html file in your projects folder. third picture - that's what i wanted to achieve. thank you so much and also for your patience! i tend to stick with those (little) problems just out of curiosity:-)

Comment: You welcome, so pls don't forget to close the question by mark as answered in the check mark :)

Answer (score 0):

`npm install http-server -g`

if you not installed npm then,

`sudo apt-get install npm`

then,after installation

run this cammand to start local server

`http-server`